# Ошибка (На устройстве не осталось свободного места.)

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux

Я купил новый SSD диск на 256gb, решил накатить на него Kali Linux, скачал с официального сайта дистрибутив 2021.2 . Установил успешно, но когда решил установить недостающие файлы через терминал командой `sudo apt dist-upgrade` терминал начал выдавать ошибку о нехватке места. Я ввел команду `sudo df -h` и увидел следующее: [image]

Подскажите что делать пожалуйста :)

Comment: запустите любой линукс с live cd/usb, запустите там программу gparted. Потом уменьшите размер раздела /dev/nvme0n1p4 (это home), потом подвиньте его правее, и потом получится увеличить нужный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Почитать что-нибудь о разделах диска применительно к линуксу.
2. Установить заново с ручной разметкой диска, выделив на корневой раздел ( `/` ) хотя бы 20 Гб. Сейчас там 11 и этого действительно мало.

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Comment: Пишет что максимум - 12 Gb для этого раздела

Comment: Хотя сначала можно попытаться просто увеличить раздел. Не знаю, как кали линуксе называется подходящая утилита, но наверняка есть.

Comment: @kiwi да не может быть. Наверное другие разделы ещё есть  Сначала удалить все разделы, а потом создать заново.

Comment: я уменьшил размер у раздела в котором 240гб было и все равно пишет что 12 это максимум...

Comment: Вообще такого ограничения нет. Возможно, между этими разделами есть ещё какой-то раздел и он препятствует. Тогда все же лучше вообще установить по новой, предварительно удалив все разделы.